# Azure Functions API call from Power Automate Flow

Tags: azure-functions, power-automate, power-platform

I have an Azure function API which processes documents using Azure Document Intelligence. The final JSON response contains data extracted from input documents.

I tried calling the Azure Functions API from postman and it worked fine.
I also tried calling the Azure Functions API from UiPath and it seems to work fine.

But, when I tried calling from Power Automate Flow (HTTP request), I get response from API saying "No attachments found". My guess is that the HTTP request from Power Automate Flow needs some more parameters which out of the box does not contain.

[image]

[image]

Here is the Postman Payload.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So show us a payload from postman that works. How are we supposed to know what the function expects? You haven’t given us that insight and it’s imperative to being able to assist.

Comment: @Skin i have added the postman payloads to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the payload received on the function side along with the headers passed in from the request?

Comment: @Svj Can you please share your function code?

Comment: @Skin I tried via CURL and it worked fine. 
curl --location --request GET 'https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?processtype=extractpdf' --header 'x-functions-key: XXX' --form '=@"/home/xxx/Downloads/Invoice-B1AA7382-0006.pdf"'. And i tried the same with PHP and that works too. The only difference is see from Power Automate HTTP call is that the BODY portion says "microsoft.graph,fileAttachment".

Comment: @Skin Below is what PowerAutomat HTTP request is sending.
{"uri":"https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?processtype=extractpdf",
"method":"POST",
"headers":{"x-functions-key":"XXX"},
"body":
{
"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
"id":"XXX",
"lastModifiedDateTime":"2024-01-12T06:12:46+00:00",
"name":"filename.pdf",
"contentType":"application/pdf",
"size":935646,"isInline":false,
"contentBytes":"XXX"
}
}

Comment: @Svj you are sending file as a form data so, you need to accept the attachment in logic app as a multipart data too. check this https://medium.com/version-1/azure-logic-apps-how-to-post-multipart-and-form-data-dbc2e8640c67

Comment: No, ‍♂️ I mean the successful call from postman. Do some analysis on a working execution and work back from there. It’s a simple, logical approach.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin yes I tried sending Content-Type: multipart/form-data but this is getting set on the header and not in the body.

Comment: @Svj Yes but it should work as its working for me, I have created a function which return the file name and getting expected output like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xpovviL.png)

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin i tried CURL again with "multipart/form-data" it passed, "application/json" failed, "application/pdf" failed. Now, it is clearly evident that AzureFunctions is expecting form-data. My concern is that Power Automate, eventhough I added "multipart/form-data" as "Content-Type", it is adding another "contenType":"application/pdf" into the body by default.

Comment: @Svj are you getting any error while using Content-Type: multipart/form-data in power automate?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin yes, it says "no attachment found". I can see PA HTTP contains header parameter as "multipart/form-data" but it also contains another field in the BODY by default "contenType":"application/pdf"

Comment: @Svj Can you please share the screenshot of the HTTP action and how you are sending the data for Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I have added the screenshot into the OP.

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin added screenshot from PA as well now. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256567/discussion-between-ikhtesam-afrin-and-svj).